# Codeigniter Display Image With Open Library API

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, oop

I am retrieving data from my MySQL database, and displaying a table including;

- `item_id`
- `item_image` (empty)
- `item_title`
- `item_isbn` (contains hyphens)

The code I have so far works, in the sense that I am able to retrieve the data and display it in a simple table.

My code so far;

**model**

```
class Items_model extends CI_Model {
    public function itemList() {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM item LIMIT 10");
        return $query->result_array();
    }        
}
```

**view**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>ID</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Image</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Title</strong></td>
        <td><strong>ISBN</strong></td>
    </tr>
<?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $item['item_id']; ?></td>         
            <td><?php echo $item['item_image']; ?></td>   
            <td><?php echo $item['item_title']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $item['item_isbn']; ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

**controller**

```
class Items extends CI_Controller {
    public function index() {
        $data['items'] = $this->items_model->itemList();        
        $this->load->view('item_view', $data);
    }
}
```

I want to use the book's ISBN, retrieve the book cover using [Open Library Covers API](https://openlibrary.org/dev/docs/api/covers) and populate the image field in the html table.

Apparently this is possible by using the following URL pattern;

```
http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/isbn/0385472579-S.jpg
```

I have tried the following code in my view but it doesn't work;

```
<td><img src="<?php echo ('http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/isbn/'. stripslashes($item['item_isbn']) .'-S.jpg');?>"/></td>
```

Ideally I would like to display a standard 'No Image Found' jpg, if I'm unable to retrieve an image using Open Library API also, but I'm sure I can work this part out on my own (hopefully!).

Any advice would be appreciated, very new to Codeigniter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have valid ISBN's stored in your database, please change your view to the following:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>ID</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Image</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Title</strong></td>
        <td><strong>ISBN</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $item['item_id']; ?></td>
            <td><img src="http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/isbn/<?php echo $item['item_isbn']; ?>-S.jpg" /></td>
            <td><?php echo $item['item_title']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $item['item_isbn']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

If an image is not found, a 1px by 1px transparent pixel is displayed.

So the code syntax to display the image is:

```
<img src="http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/isbn/<?php echo $item['item_isbn']; ?>-S.jpg" />
```

[Resulting screenshot from my test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxooZ.png)

**Update** (If No Image Found)

As per the documentation:

> By default it returns a blank image if the cover cannot be found. If
>   you append ?default=false to the end of the URL, then it returns a 404
>   instead.

To add your own fallback image, you could append this parameter to the image URL, and then check if the file doesn't exist.

There are multiple ways to check if a file exists or not. Using curl would probably be the most graceful but here is a...

**Quick & Dirty Method**

This uses a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) in conjunction with the [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) function to handle the fallback. You will need to ensure that GD (image processing library) support is enabled in your version of PHP for this.

```
<img src="<?php echo (!getimagesize('http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/isbn/' . $item['item_isbn'] . '-S.jpg?default=false')) ? '/path/to/your-image.jpg' : 'http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/isbn/' . $item['item_isbn'] . '-S.jpg'; ?>" />
```

Think of the ternary operator syntax like an inline if/else statement.

Comment: @johnny_s If you are happy with my answer can you please accept it. Thanks!